# How do I write a validation for params passed from form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have run into a problem where I am not sure how to validate my data.

For example

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  # has the boolean flag visible
  # some custom validation to come
end
```

I have a form that allows me to edit a parent and the children of a parent at the same time using accepts_nested_attributes. I want to create validation that only allows 1 child to be visible at a time. One would think this is simple.

However, that doesn't seem to be the case. An example

Say I have in the database

```
parent - A
  -> child 1, not visible
  -> child 2, visible
```

and on my form

I create a 3rd child and set the visibility of child 2 to not visible

```
parent - A
  -> child 1, not visible
  -> child 2, not visible
  -> child 3, visible

# note the above data is coming from the form (it's not in the db yet)
```

If I do the validation and hit the database, it still thinks child 2 is visible (which it is in the database), but it's not in memory (i.e. passed in via params from the form). I tried running my validation on the in memory data, but I am not sure how go about achieving this.

Any ideas?

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: I first thought validating in the parent would solve this issue, but reconsidered... Have you tried to set all visible attributes of the children to false in the db before updating (plus using a custom validator in the parent)? Not the most elegant solution, though.

Comment: No I never thought of that and not too fond of it, but in desperate times ... thanks for the suggestion, I might have to actually do something like that :/

Comment: In your form are you using radio buttons for setting the visibility of the children?

Comment: No, a checkbox since it's a boolean value.

Comment: I tried getting the parent of the child and then getting the parents children, hoping the data in memory would be the same as the params, but that doesn't seem to be the case.